# Can i know train and test accuracy individually if am using (cross_val_score)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, cross-validation

I used a random-forest classifier to classify my dataset; I want to use cross-validation; my problem is I could not find a way to know the accuracy of train and test splits, so is this possible?
here is the code I used, which tell me about the

```
X_test, X_rem, y_test, y_rem = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.1)

X_valid, X_train, y_valid, y_train = train_test_split(X_rem,y_rem, train_size=0.80)


    cv = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=1, shuffle=True)
    # create model
    model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators =400)
        

    scoresranP = cross_val_score(model, X_rem, y_rem, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
    
    print('Accuracy of Random Forest: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scoresranP), std(scoresranP)))
```

If I am right, in this case, the "scoresranP" will give me the training accuracy, so can I get the test accuracy using the test split?
I am wrong. Can anyone tell me if I can using cross_val_score with three splits (train, valid, test)?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct Random Forest does not gives you a training accuracy as it is a regression learning method.

Comment: I think I can if am using a model.predict(), but here I want to use cross-validation